# Need to speed up pattern matching in jagged array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pattern-matching, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array, 20 by 20. I try to match 700 different patterns that are built like smaller jagged arrays. The values that are matched (bytes OR:ed together) can be "player", "opponent", "empty" or "don't care" or a mix of these. The pattern size ranges from 4x4 to 7x7.

How can I speed this up? I am sure there is a better way to do this. Right now it takes around a second to check for all the patterns. I need to know all the matches, not just once for each pattern.

```
// Iterate through all patterns
for( int patNum = 0; patNum < whitePatterns.Length; patNum++)
{
    // Get current pattern
    pat = whitePatterns[patNum];

    col = pat.pattern.Length;
    row = pat.pattern[0].Length;

    for (int x = 0; x < myBoard.Size - col + 1; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < myBoard.Size - row + 1; ++y)
        {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < col; ++xx)
                for (int yy = 0; yy < row; ++yy)
                {
                    count++;
                    if ((myBoard.board[x + xx][y + yy] & pat.pattern[xx][yy]) == 0)
                    {
                        goto loopY;
                    }
                }

            // Found a match!

            loopY: ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the pattern iterator with a Parallel.ForEach()??

Comment: There is no magic way around the brute-force attack. But it does seems very well suited for parallelization.

Comment: You could use a dictionary with 4x4 combinations. This should make a total or partial lookup very quick, however creating such a dictionary and and providing the lookup will be additional complexity and take some time.

Comment: I am using Unity that uses Mono 2.6 and looks like it doesn't support Parallel.ForEach. Will find a way to try and parallelize the pattern loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes brute-force is the best approach.  However, you're unlikely to be taking advantage of your CPU.  As a very basic start, use parallelisation to take full advantage of your machines processing power.

```
Parallel.ForEach(whitePatterns, wp =>
{
int col = wp.pattern.Length;
int row = wp.pattern[0].Length;
for (int x = 0; x < myBoard.Size - col + 1; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < myBoard.Size - row + 1; ++y)        
    {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < col; ++xx)
            for (int yy = 0; yy < row; ++yy)
        {
            count++;
            if ((myBoard.board[x + xx][y + yy] & wp.pattern[xx][yy]) == 0)
            {
                goto loopY;

            }
        }

        // Found a match!

    loopY: ;
    }       
}
});
```

Comment: Depending on the amount of work to do you may want to change which `for` you turn in to a `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For`. For 700 items to test the level in this answer may be the right one. I highly recommend checking out the free book by Microsoft "[Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)". In particular look at the anti-pattern "TOO FINE-GRAINED, TOO COARSE GRAINED" to learn more about parallelizing nested `for` loops.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for that.  I haven't come across that before.  I'm genuinely going to enjoy the read. :-)

Comment: Using Unity that doesn't support Parallel.ForEach. will check how to do it in Unity.

Comment: Hi Jon, not sure if you get this, I found a version that works with .Net 3.5. It's a parallel.for, it works like a charm when just iterating over the length of whitepatterns and printing the index, but I get an array out of bounds if I try it in the above code. Any clue what could cause that? Do I need a lock of some sort for any of the code?

Comment: @Andreas That's great.  You shouldn't need any lock.  With the array out of bounds, somewhere a number is being generated that is beyond the extent of one of your arrays, but without the full code, I cannot be sure where.  I can only suggest that you place some global variables outside the Parallel.For loop to capture col, row, x, y, xx and wp.  Then wrap Parallel.For within a try and for each loop, write the values of current variables to the global ones, set a break point at the point of exception and the global variables should give you some insight into why its failing.

Comment: @Andreas as another thought, have you correctly set the values in the Parallel.For?  I think you should have `Parallel.For(0, whitePatterns.Length, wp => { pat = whitePatterns[wp]; });` from memory.

Comment: Got it working thanks :) had missed to declare col and row inside the loop. Unfortunately it didn't speed up the algorithm, could be that the implementation isn't as efficent as the built in one. Tried with a foreach to, and it was even slower. I forgot to say that the reason it takes 1,5 seconds is I do this 8 times, rotated 4 times, then mirrored and rotated to find all matches. So a whole lot of matching, best bet looks like a better algorithm. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Andreas, That is strange, as you say its perhaps the implementation.  Never-the-less, you're welcome and hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a fixed set of patterns and you want to search the game board for all occurrences of those patterns.

This sounds suspiciously like having a fixed set of search strings that you want to find over a large body of text.

I'm not saying that it would be *easy*, but you could build a state machine from that fixed set of patterns and then run what is essentially a modified the Aho-Corasick algorithm on it.

Actually, what you'd do is each line of each pattern is considered a "string", and you build the Aho-Corasick tree structure from those patterns. You then run through the entire game board to find all of the matching strings. Your result will be a set of pattern rows with their starting addresses (row, col) and pattern numbers.

Sort those results by pattern number, row number (row number in the pattern, that is), starting column, and starting row. Then you can go sequentially through that sorted list and pick out matching patterns. A pattern matches if its first row starts at game board position (row, col), next row starts at game board position (row+1, col), etc.

It will take some (small) amount of time to generate the state machine, but you only have to do that once. After that, the searches are incredibly quick. Sorting the results and picking out the matches would be very fast.

I built an Aho-Corasick pattern matcher in C# that might help you get started. See my article, [Aho-Corasick Revisited](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look at your article. It would require some work with the patterns but might be worth it in the end :)